# Does completing "Establish a Temple to Ibrundul" count as taking Piety quests?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

I came across a situation while playing Lords of Waterdeep with the Scoundrels of Skullport expansion.

I had completed the *Sanctify a Desecrated Temple* plot quest, which provides a white cube whenever I take a Piety quest. Later in the game I completed the *Establish a Temple to Ibrandul* quest, which as the reward has me take all quests from Cliffwatch Inn.

If any of those quests are Piety quests, do I get a white cube for each of them as a result of the plot quest?

I don't have images, but I imagine there are similar plot quests for when you take the other quest types and this same situation would apply.

My thought is that since both cards use the word **take**, then the plot quest reward would be triggered and I'd get white cubes for each Piety quest present, but is this the case?

[image: quests in question]

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to find an official answer for you but I would say that yes, you're interpreting it correctly. The wording in Lords of Waterdeep is usually quite clear and the keyword is the same on both cards. Due to the first card you get a cube each time you **take** a Piety quest and the second card instructs you to **take** a number of quest cards. This means that you will get a cube per Piety quest taken.